# How can you send email to a Gmail Contact Group?

Tags: gmail, contact-groups

I'm using Android 4.1 on a Droid Razr M.

Is there any way to send an email to a contact Group?

I've read several [posts](http://www.ehow.com/how_8543114_send-email-group-gmail-android.html) that show how to do this but none of them actually work.

There is also an app ([GroupU](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.groupu.android&hl=en)) but it would be nice to be able to send to groups *within* Gmail.

Comment: You can't send them within gmail app. You need to create Google group for that.  See http://m.techrepublic.com/blog/google-in-the-enterprise/how-to-send-email-to-groups-efficiently-with-google-apps/1483

Answer (score 0):

I spent some time checking for a solution myself, and here are my conclusions.

1. We will never be able to send to groups *within* Gmail for Android. I think it's a problem Google will never solve maybe because they want us to use Google Plus to send to groups (i.e. Circles).
2. To send to Gmail groups outside of Gmail, I found that using Go Contacts is the best way. Gmail Group Share (Free) is also working, but it shows groups of only one Google Account at time.

Comment: Fast forward to now, Google Plus is no longer available, and Gmail Group Share cannot be found anymore.

Answer (score -1):

This is actually very easy:

1. Go to your Admin Console & click on “Groups”
2. Create a Group of Users (e.g.: “mygroup”) in your Google Apps Admin Console. Then the group will have an email address like @mydomain. com

Comment: How do I get to the Admin Console?
Is that the Admin in Gmail or in my Google Account?
Does this work if I am not using the paid Google Apps?

Comment: For most users with personal Gmail addresses, I'm afraid this answer is not something that can be achieved easily...

Answer (score -2):

Use gmail group share, go to the settings and click to show the hidden group and system group.

Comment: As of current writing, I'm afraid it's unclear what this refers to; whether it referred to a built-in feature, or a 3rd-party app (based on [another answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/49786/44325))